# guardar registros en phpmyadmin mediante formulario

Tags: php

estoy intentando introducir datos en la base de datos phpmyadmin desde un formulario php, pero no consigo que me haga los registros correctamente. No consigo averiguar cuál es el error

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?

include "includes/conexionBD.php";
if (!isset($accion)){
        echo"
        <html>
        <head><title>Guardar datos en la base</title></head>
        <body>
<h3>Guardar datos en la base</h3>
<form name="form1" method="post"

  <p>Nombre:<br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
  </p>
  <p>Apellido:<br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido1">
  </p>
  <p>Dirección:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Direccion">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Guardar Datos">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>";
}elseif($accion=="guardar"){
  include"includes/conexionBD.php";
  $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO personas  (nombre, apellido1,Direccion)
    VALUES ($nombre,$apellido1,$Direccion) ",$conexion);
  echo" <html>


?>
```

> conexionBD.php

```
<?php
        define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
        define("USUARIO", "root");
        define("CONTRASENA", "");
        define("BASEDATOS", "cochespersonas");

        $enlaceBD = mysqli_connect( SERVIDOR,USUARIO, CONTRASENA, BASEDATOS);

        $enlaceBD->set_charset("utf8");

        if( !$enlaceBD )
        {
            echo "La conexión no se ha podido establecer";
            exit();
        }
?>
```

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: pues que no me registra el nombre el apellido y la dirección en la base de datos

Comment: `mysql_query` es una funcion deprecated, utiliza `mysqli_query` por seguridad.

Comment: phpmyadmin es solo un gestor de base de datos. No es la base de datos.

Comment: la base de datos está alojada ahí, tiene tres campos: nombre apellido1 y Dirección

Answer (score 0):

Hola por lo que puedo notar es que tienes un relajo de código y todo revuelto.

Esto que hice es básicamente lo que tu quieres hacer, pero de una formas más sencilla y entendible.

Espero que te pueda servir.

> conexionBD.php

```
<?php
//parametros de la base de datos
$usuario='root';
$password='root';
$servidor='localhost';
$bd_name = 'nombre_bd';

// Realiza conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $bd_name) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos'. mysqli_error());
?>
```

> formulario.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guardar datos en la base</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Guardar datos en la base</h3>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="registra.php">
          <p>Nombre:<br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
          </p>
          <p>Apellido:<br>
            <input type="text" name="apellido">
          </p>
          <p>Dirección:<br>
            <input type="text" name="direccion">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Guardar Datos">
          </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> registra.php

```
<html>   
<head>   
<title>Guardar datos en la base</title>   
</head>   

<body>   
<?php   

// Recibimos por POST los datos del formulario   

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];   
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];   
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];   

// Abrimos la conexion a la base de datos   
include ('includes/conexionBD.php'); 

$query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido, direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$direccion')";    

if (mysqli_query($query)){
echo "<p>Registro agregado.</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>No se agregó.</p>";
} 

?>   
</body>   

</html>
```

Comment: Tu código da el siguiente error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in line..