# conexión bases de datos php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, formularios

Buenas estoy probando introducir registros en phpmyadmin a través de un formulando y utilizando php. No consigo que me registre los datos y no sé el motivo. Alguna ayuda?

Dejo el código.

```
    <?php
        define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
        define("USUARIO", "root");
        define("CONTRASENA", "");
        define("BASEDATOS", "cochespersonas");

        $enlaceBD = mysqli_connect( SERVIDOR,USUARIO, CONTRASENA, BASEDATOS);

        $enlaceBD->set_charset("utf8");

        if( !$enlaceBD )
        {
            echo "La conexión no se ha podido establecer";
            exit();
        }
?>

<html>   
<head>   
<title>Guardar datos en la base</title>   
</head>   

<body>   
<?php   

// Recibimos por POST los datos del formulario   

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];   
$apellido1 = $_POST["apellido1"];   
$Direccion = $_POST["Direccion"];   

// Abrimos la conexion a la base de datos   
include ('conexionBD.php'); 

$query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')";    

if (mysqli_init($query)){
echo "<p>Registro agregado.</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>No se agregó.</p>";
} 
?>   
</body>   

</html>   

<html>
<head>
    <title>Guardar datos en la base</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Guardar datos en la base</h3>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="nuevopropietario.php">
          <p>Nombre:<br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
          </p>
          <p>Apellido:<br>
            <input type="text" name="apellido1">
          </p>
          <p>Direccion:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Guardar Datos">
          </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [guardar registros en phpmyadmin mediante formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209295/guardar-registros-en-phpmyadmin-mediante-formulario)

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano no estas realizando la query realmente. Aparte phpmyadmin no es una bbdd, es una herramienta para 'administrar' una bbdd (usualmente mysql)

Comment: Creo que casi lo tienes. Cambia esta línea: `if (mysqli_init($query)){` por esto: `if (mysqli_query($enlaceBD,$query)){` Si ocurre algún error y quieres saber cuál es, puedes poner el código así: **`if (mysqli_query($enlaceBD,$query)){ echo "<p>Registro agregado.</p>"; } else { echo "<p>No se agregó. Error: ".mysqli_error($enlaceBD)."</p>";}`** Cuando funcione debes saber que a tu código le quedan todavía muchas cosas por mejorar, sobre todo con respecto a la seguridad.

Comment: tampoco funciona con la sugerencia que me has hecho

Comment: Ahora sí, gracias.

Comment: Sé más específico. No es lo mismo decir *tampoco funciona*  que decir, no funciona, me imprime tal cosa en pantalla, no me imprime nada, se resetea el equipo, etc. ¿Qué comportamiento tiene? Qué error imprime?  ¿Agregaste esto en el `else`: `mysqli_error($enlaceBD)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas. Los voy a enumerar según van apareciendo y luego sugeriré una corrección:

1. No controlas si los datos fueron pasados realmente por POST
2. No es seguro: debes usar consultas preparadas
3. No usas la conexión para hacer la inserción
4. No controlas si **realmente** hubo una inserción

Propongo esto:

```
<?php
        define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
        define("USUARIO", "root");
        define("CONTRASENA", "");
        define("BASEDATOS", "cochespersonas");

        $enlaceBD = mysqli_connect( SERVIDOR,USUARIO, CONTRASENA, BASEDATOS);

        $enlaceBD->set_charset("utf8");

        if( !$enlaceBD )
        {
            echo "La conexión no se ha podido establecer";
            exit();
        }
?>

<html>   
<head>   
<title>Guardar datos en la base</title>   
</head>   

<body>   
<?php   

// Recibimos por POST los datos del formulario   

$nombre =    (empty($_POST["nombre"]))    ? NULL : $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido1 = (empty($_POST["apellido1"])) ? NULL : $_POST["apellido1"];   
$Direccion = (empty($_POST["Direccion"])) ? NULL : $_POST["Direccion"];   
if ($nombre&&$apelllido1&&$Direccion){
    // Abrimos la conexion a la base de datos   
    include ('conexionBD.php'); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($enlaceBD,$query)) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $nombre,$apelllido1,$Direccion);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $filas=mysqli_affected_rows($enlaceBD);
        $msg="Filas insertadas: $filas";
    }else{
        $msg="No se pudo insertar. Error: ".mysqli_error($enlaceBD);
    }
}else{
    $msg="Faltan datos en el POST";
}
echo $msg;
?>   
</body>   

</html>   

<html>
<head>
    <title>Guardar datos en la base</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Guardar datos en la base</h3>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="nuevopropietario.php">
          <p>Nombre:<br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
          </p>
          <p>Apellido:<br>
            <input type="text" name="apellido1">
          </p>
          <p>Direccion:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Guardar Datos">
          </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

El código se puede todavía mejorar un poco más. Puedes por ejemplo establecer directamente el juego de caracteres en la cadena de conexión. Y si quieres escribir un código más entendible, más claro y más moderno, puedes pasar del modo procedural al modo orientado a objetos...